# How can set this as first day of each day for power bi, I tried to put measure but measure cannot out as row

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I wish to set the date at the column "date" as each week first day, for this case, is 9/8 across all row
[image]

e.g.
Name, first Date, total amount for all 7 days
people 1, 9/8, 40K
people 2, 9/8, 40K

on top i have date for each day (7 day), Also wish to know how can i show the 7 day even if there is no data, that will be best